# Prepared statement insert into MySQL from Java

Tags: java, mysql

Ok, I know this has been beaten to death in other posts but I have tried to no avail to get this INSERT command to work. I am using MySQL 5.6 with a JDBC connector. I am reading in String variables from a GUI and trying to use them in the INSERT. I have tried using ", `, ' and every combination out there to do this and nothing. This is a pretty straight forward application so what am I missing. Yes the variables do have values in them, I checked.

```
              try
                 {  

                    String sql = "INSERT INTO customer(firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, phone, email)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, custFirst);
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, custLast);
                    preparedStatement.setString(3, custAddress);
                    preparedStatement.setString(4, custCity);
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, custState);
                    preparedStatement.setString(6, custZip);
                    preparedStatement.setString(7, custPhone);
                    preparedStatement.setString(8, custEmail);

                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); 

                 }
              catch(Exception err)
                 {
                     System.err.println("Error: " + err.getMessage());
                 }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you tell us what happens? Do we guess?

Comment: What's the expected and actual result? And can you format your code properly?

Comment: Ok, here's the deal. I forgot to include a connect statement so I was never connecting to the database. Yeah I know, I'm an idiot...Once I connected to the database it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space in your query statement:

```
"INSERT INTO customer(firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, phone, email)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                                                                                  ^
```

should be

```
"INSERT INTO customer(firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, phone, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it really really helps if you are connected to the database BEFORE you try to insert something into it. I had forgot to include a connect statement in my code. Once I added that it worked like a charm. Imagine that...